# Popup in a external window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap & jQuery to develop an application and I need to show a div which contains two tables on a popup. Until now I have use the modal plugin from bootstrap but now I have the need of show it in a external and floating 'small' (~800x600) window, which I can close, minimize, etc.

I have been searching how to do it but only found this plugin which works with urls: jquery.popupWindow.js (http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html but what I need is to show the content of a div (The idea is generate programmatically two tables, append it to a div, and show it in a external window)

Anyone could help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving you the idea, Assume their are two windows `parent.html` and `child.html`

in parent.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var output = "data";
        var OpenWindow = window.open("child.html", "mywin", '');
        OpenWindow.dataFromParent = output; // dataFromParent is a variable in child.html
        OpenWindow.init();
    });
</script>
```

in child.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataFromParent;    
    function init() {
        document.write(dataFromParent);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: But it isn't a .html document. I'm creating the div programmatically ( document.createElement("div"), and then I'm appending my tables (also generated dynamically) auxDiv.appendChild(table); Now I'm appending that to a bootstrap-modal and what I want is to show the div in a external popup.

Comment: Whatever you have, just store it in a variable named `output` and `child.html` is just the name of the popup window. Then when you will do `OpenWindow.dataFromParent = output;` it will append the content to the external window which you can minimize, close or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this,  I use a div within the main page.

This is the HTML placed just before the body close tag

```
<div id="popup">
<div id="popupcontent">
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the css

```
#popup {
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    top:13%;
    left:40%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:#0073EA solid 4px;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:20px;

}
```

When populating and displaying a div like this from a jquery event handler, your code will look something like this:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(e) {  

  var popupdata = "Some latin stuff used as a placeholder";

  $('#popupcontent').html(popupdata);

   $('#popup').show();


});
```

Hopefully this helps.